# При hover мигают углы кнопки и полей ввода в Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Всем привет.
В Firefox при hover на кнопку и полей ввода мигают углы.
[Вот как это выглядит.](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/HVDXstn1P_tIZw)

```css
input {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #72879F;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F0F2F4;
  height: 40px;
  width: 220px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

input:hover {
  background: #57687a;
}
```